# Install openjdk 7 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, java, openjdk

I cannot install openjdk-7-jdk on Ubuntu 16.04. When I try to
`user@pc$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`, it fails with:

```
...
Depends: libgif4 (>= 4.1.4) but it is not installable
...
```

So I check for this `libgif` package, but it looks like it is deleted: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/libgif4/4.1.6-11

So how do I install openjdk-7 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: The current version for 16.04 is openjdk-8 8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3. Do you need an older version? or would installing openjdk-8 meet your needs?

Comment: @J.Starnes yes, I need an older version, I specifically mentioned both the version (7) and the Java vendor (OpenJDK) in the question.